# Kalman-Bucy filter: how does a prior mean change, alter the posterior?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior, kalman-filter

I have a question on Kalman-Bucy filter:

The prior distribution is $g \sim N(0,σ_g^2 )$, signal is $ds=(μ+g_t )dt+σdZ_t$, posterior distribution becomes $g_t \sim N((\hat{g_t},\hatσ_t^2)$. Here,$σ_g,μ,σ$ are constants.

Now, if I change the prior mean from 0 to $a$, where $a$ is a constant, other things remain the same, may I know how the posterior distribution would change?

Comment: The fundamental assumptions of the filter are that the noise is centered, and that it is uncorrelated.  If you violate those, you stop having a filter.

Comment: Changing the prior mean of $g$ is equivalent to changing the value of $\mu$.